# Managing paradigm packs and roles

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

So I've now got Serah to lv99 Ravager and lv99 Medic, and Noel to lv99 Commando and lv99 Sentinel. Is there any point in using the other roles? Other than just to level up the stats?

For example I notice that although Serah is lv99 medic, she only has about 7 skills (not at my ps3) which seems odd to me.

As this is the case I'm always running `Relentless Assault`(`RAV`,`RAV`,`COM`) which is working fine so far, short of swapping in Flanitor occasionally for some heals I've not needed anything else.

If I carry on with this play style, is there actually any point at all in me levelling up any `COM` monsters? I've been levelling and infusing my `RAV` to allow him access to the different element spells, but otherwise I can't see much point in using the other roles.

Do I just keep playing and will I get better monsters as I play through? So far I've not really needed to play about with Monsters at all, and I feel reading questions on here that I'm missing out.

I've not used the `Wide` or `Cross` paradigm styles either. I stick with `Regular` the whole time.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.  You seem to be asking "Am I playing wrong?"  I'm not sure how someone else is going to be able to asnwer that for you.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify the advantages of levelling and playing with monsters who share the strongest roles of your two main characters. Apologies if it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, infusing monsters isn't really required.  You can run through the game with stock monsters without any difficulty.  It's there to provide an extra level of customization.

I went through the whole game with a level ~40 Red Chocobo.  These are late bloomers, so for the most part, his attack was around 200/250.  Not very high at all.

You will get different monsters as you play; not necessarily better.  Each one has it's own unique skillset and abilities.

My own experience shows that for the most part, Aggression (COM, COM, RAV) is enough for most of the game.  Only for the really strong monsters (Tonberries, Steppe bosses, etc.) do you really need to tweak your paradigms and the monsters.

Comment: So what benefits are to be had for levelling a `COM` monster over using Noel as a `COM` considering his other roles have so few abilities?

Comment: The benefits are due to unique abilities available to monsters that are not available to Noel.  One, off the top of my head is Armor Breaker.  When monsters have physical damage halved, Armor Breaker kicks in and ups the damage.  Another one is Haste Feeder, which the Red Chocobo gets automatically.  It will strip haste off of any monster it attacks, doing extra damage to it, and give itself haste in the process.  Phenomenally useful for the end boss, due to their constant buff refresh.

Answer (score 0):

At one point I was fighting Caius solo with Serah and a monster and I had no Sentinel monster, so Serah was a Sentinel while I used Flanitor as a Medic, switching back and forth to Saboteur for Wound/Poison so yeah, I think it's all situational and how you want to play.

You could easily play the game with Noel as a Medic and the other two as whatever else, however it seems that other characters/monsters have different abilities than other ones (for instance one might get Curasa while another does not).

I'm hoping with the DLC they'll make more instances where we need to fulfull every role in battles as for the most part you can just kill everything without so much as touching certain roles.